# Множественный update?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Нужно сделать такой запрос:

```
UPDATE first_table, second_table
SET first_table.count = first_table.count + second_table.total_count,  second_table.total_count = 0
WHERE second_table.id = :id
AND first_table.id = second_table.id
```

Значение из таблицы `second_table.total_count` прибавить к `first_table.count` и потом `second_table.total_count` задать значение - `0`

Если убрать `second_table.total_count = 0` из запроса, то все работает.

Это конечно же можно было бы сделать двумя запросами, но хотелось бы узнать, можно ли обойтись одним запросом и как это сделать ?

Comment: У Вас и в запросе HERE или вы криво скопировали? И определитесь вам count = 0 нужен или total_count = 0

Comment: @InDevX криво скопировал. Поправил!